# Statistics question! I am new here! And I am STUMPED on the Dice rolling question!

Tags: probability-or-statistics, homework

I am new here! I need some help!

A regular dice has six faces, with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. A typical roll of a dice will land on one of the 6 faces, and the number that is displayed can be considered as output for that throw. Construct a visual outcome for 100, 1000, 10000, and million throws of a regular dice. Now, consider a loaded dice. This particular dice is likely to land on a face with even number greater than 3, thrice as more as any other number. Construct a visual outcome for the same number of throws for this loaded dice. Compare the two outputs by organizing them neatly using GraphicsGrid

I am only 14 years old. So i am having a hard time with this one!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is pure Homework an the Author shows no effort what so ever.

Comment: Sorry. Everything i have done up until this point has been basic math! 
list1=List[1,2,3,4,5,6]
I assume the first part would be easy. RandomVariate[List1]

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and we can help you out.  And being 14 isn't a good excuse for not trying. [This kid](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/monty/) made a voice activated personal assistant with a Raspberry Pi, and he's only 13.

Comment: But I am not exactly sure how to run the same Randomizer 100, 1000, and 10000 times. Without just finding the probability and multiplying it! And it becomes more of a headeache when it occurs more often!

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34861).

Comment: Wow that is very cool!

Comment: Hey - I was 14 once too.

Comment: "thrice as more as any other number" --- thrice as more?

Comment: A. Rex, I rolled back your last edit and re-instated the body of your question. Please do not remove the body of your question through edits; any answers you might receive won't make any sense to future readers any more.

Comment: Study bob's answer, and edit your question to show what you did. Until then, this one's on hold.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, because you need to come up with the answer yourself.  Some ideas, however.

First, have a look at `Range`, which will help you in generating the list of numbers you need.

Second, look at `RandomChoice` instead of `RandomVariate`.  The former gives you the opportunity to choose multiple numbers at a time.

Third, look at `Histogram`, which will help you get a visualization of your output.

Once you get to this point, you should be able to answer most of the parts of your own question.  The "weighted die" part can be simulated with options found in the RandomChoice documentation, but I would suggest you get your visualizations for the unweighted die first.